# Ошибка при импорте из другого файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, gui

Есть два файла `untitled2.py` и `intakes.py`. Необходимо, что бы при нажатии кнопки в `untitled2.py` открывалось окно из `intakes.py`.

При попытки импортировать в файл `untitled2.py` класс из `intakes.py` выдается ошибку:

> cannot import name 'intakesWindow' from 'intakes' 
>     C:\Users\n12m\Desktop\asd\intakes.py

Оба файла находятся в одной папке.

**untitled2.py:**

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
#from intakes import intakesWindow

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1042, 573)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 771, 531))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.Feed = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Feed.setObjectName("Feed")
        self.graphWidget = MyPlot(self.Feed)
        self.graphWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 741, 431))
        self.graphWidget.setObjectName("graphWidget")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.Feed)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 741, 41))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Feed, "")
        self.Water = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Water.setObjectName("Water")
        self.graphWidget_2 = MyPlot(self.Water)
        self.graphWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 741, 431))
        self.graphWidget_2.setObjectName("graphWidget_2")
        self.layoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.Water)
        self.layoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 741, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_2.setObjectName("layoutWidget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_7.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_8.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_9.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_10.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_10)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_11)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_12.setFont(font)
        self.label_12.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_12.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_12)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Water, "")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 10, 241, 531))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 221, 501))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.listWidget.setFont(font)
        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item_1 = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        item_1.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item_1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.listViewDClicked)

        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(-1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def showIntakes(self):
        self.intakes = intakesWindow()
        self.intakes.show()

    def listViewDClicked(self):
        item = self.listWidget.currentItem()
        if item.text() == 'Потребление':
            self.showIntakes()


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Feed), _translate("MainWindow", "Feed"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Water), _translate("MainWindow", "Water"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Модули"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Потребление"))
        item_1 = self.listWidget.item(1)
        item_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item1"))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setupUi(self)

        d = 31
        x = np.arange(d)
        y1 = x

        self.barFeed = MyBarGraphItem()
        self.barFeed.setAttr(brushes=[pg.QtGui.QColor(128, 128, 128) for x in range(d)], x=x, y=y1-0.5*x, height=y1, width= 0.7)

        self.barWater = MyBarGraphItem()
        self.barWater.setAttr(brushes=[pg.QtGui.QColor(0, 139, 139) for x in range(d)],x=x, y=y1-0.5*x, height=y1, width= 0.7)

        self.graphWidget.addBars(self.barFeed)
        self.graphWidget_2.addBars(self.barWater)

class MyBarGraphItem(pg.BarGraphItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def setAttr(self, **opts):
        #print(opts)
        if 'x' in opts:
            self.x = opts['x']
        if 'height' in opts:
            self.height = opts['height']
        if 'width' in opts:
            self.width = opts['width']
        if 'brushes' in opts:
            self.brushes = opts['brushes']
        if 'y' in opts:
            self.y = opts['y']
        super().setOpts(**opts)

class MyPlot(PlotWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.bars = None
        self.beforeSelected = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        pos = self.getPlotItem().vb.mapSceneToView(ev.pos())
        if self.bars is not None:
            x, y = pos.x(), pos.y()
            #print(f'\nВкладка =  {self.objectName()}')
            if self.objectName() == "graphWidget":
                for i, _ in enumerate(self.bars.x):
                    if self.bars.x[i] - self.bars.width / 2 < x < self.bars.x[i] + self.bars.width / 2 \
                            and 0 < y < self.bars.height[i]:
                        self.selectedBar(i)
                        self.window().label.setText(f'bar = {i}')
                        self.window().label_2.setText(f'x = {x:.5f}')
                        self.window().label_3.setText(f'y = {y:.5f}')
                    ev.accept()
            elif self.objectName() == "graphWidget_2":
                for i, _ in enumerate(self.bars.x):
                    if self.bars.x[i] - self.bars.width / 2 < x < self.bars.x[i] + self.bars.width / 2 \
                            and 0 < y < self.bars.height[i]:
                        self.selectedBar(i)
                        self.window().label_7.setText(f'bar = {i}')
                        self.window().label_8.setText(f'x = {x:.5f}')
                        self.window().label_9.setText(f'y = {y:.5f}')
                    ev.accept()
        super().mousePressEvent(ev)

    def selectedBar(self,i):
        self.selected = i
        if self.beforeSelected is not self.selected:
            b = self.bars.brushes
            b[i] = pg.QtGui.QColor(255, 140, 0)
            self.bars.setAttr(brushes=b)
            if self.beforeSelected is not None:
                if self.objectName() == "graphWidget":
                    b[self.beforeSelected] = pg.QtGui.QColor(128, 128, 128)
                    self.bars.setAttr(brushes=b)
                elif self.objectName() == "graphWidget_2":
                    b[self.beforeSelected] = pg.QtGui.QColor(0, 139, 139)
                    self.bars.setAttr(brushes=b)
        self.beforeSelected = self.selected

    def addBars(self, bars):
        self.bars = bars
        self.addItem(self.bars)



def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**intakes.py:**

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
#from untitled2 import MyPlot

class Ui_intakesWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, intakesWindow):
        intakesWindow.setObjectName("intakesWindow")
        intakesWindow.resize(1417, 910)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(intakesWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        intakesWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        intakesWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1417, 910))
        intakesWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1417, 910))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(intakesWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 621, 761))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_17.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_17.setFont(font)
        self.label_17.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_17)
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget)
        self.spinBox.setEnabled(True)
        self.spinBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.spinBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setWrapping(False)
        self.spinBox.setFrame(False)
        self.spinBox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_18.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_18.setFont(font)
        self.label_18.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_18)
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.widget)
        self.dateEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.dateEdit.setFont(font)
        self.dateEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.dateEdit.setTimeSpec(QtCore.Qt.LocalTime)
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.dateEdit)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.widget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.widget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(639, 10, 771, 891))
        self.widget1.setObjectName("widget1")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget1)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.widget1)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.graphWidget = MyPlot(self.groupBox)
        self.graphWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 751, 351))
        self.graphWidget.setObjectName("graphWidget")
        self.widget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.widget2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 24, 751, 41))
        self.widget2.setObjectName("widget2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget2)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_8.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.widget1)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.graphWidget_2 = MyPlot(self.groupBox_2)
        self.graphWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 751, 351))
        self.graphWidget_2.setObjectName("graphWidget_2")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.groupBox_2)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 24, 751, 41))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_10.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_10)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_11)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_12.setFont(font)
        self.label_12.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_12.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_12)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_13.setFont(font)
        self.label_13.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_13)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_14.setFont(font)
        self.label_14.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_14.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_14)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_15.setFont(font)
        self.label_15.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_15)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_16.setFont(font)
        self.label_16.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_16.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_16)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox_2)
        intakesWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(intakesWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(intakesWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, intakesWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        intakesWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("intakesWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "Загон"))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "Дата"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("intakesWindow", "GroupBox"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("intakesWindow", "GroupBox"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))

class intakesWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_intakesWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(intakesWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setupUi(self)

        d = 31
        x = np.arange(d)
        y1 = x

        self.barFeed = MyBarGraphItem()
        self.barFeed.setAttr(brushes=[pg.QtGui.QColor(128, 128, 128) for x in range(d)], x=x, y=y1-0.5*x, height=y1, width= 0.7)

        self.barWater = MyBarGraphItem()
        self.barWater.setAttr(brushes=[pg.QtGui.QColor(0, 139, 139) for x in range(d)],x=x, y=y1-0.5*x, height=y1, width= 0.7)

        self.graphWidget.addBars(self.barFeed)
        self.graphWidget_2.addBars(self.barWater)



def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = intakesWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Так же интересует вопрос: В файле `intakes.py` используется тот же класс для построения графика. Его же не обязательно повторно прописывать в этом файле, и импортировать его из `untitled2.py`. Пробовал это сделать, выдает ту же ошибку

Comment: чтобы посмотреть что у вас происходит и дать вам какие-то советы, предоставьте пожалуйста воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Извините, исправил.

Comment: я не вижу кнопок в `untitled2.py`. Уточните что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Переход в другие модули будет через даблКлик из listWidget

Comment: я уже это заметил. вы попробовали мой ответ?

Comment: Да, все работает. По началу выдавало ошибку о том, что не найден модуль, но она заключалась лишь в регистре названия модуля. Спасибо за ответ. 
А в чем заключалась ошибка того, что я сделал в первый раз?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю вынести класс `class MyPlot(PlotWidget):` в отдельный модуль `myplot.py`.
Тогда ваша задача будет выглядеть так:

**untitled2.py**

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget

from intakes import intakesWindow                             # +++
from myplot import MyPlot                                     # +++

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1042, 573)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 771, 531))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.Feed = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Feed.setObjectName("Feed")
        self.graphWidget = MyPlot(self.Feed)
        self.graphWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 741, 431))
        self.graphWidget.setObjectName("graphWidget")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.Feed)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 741, 41))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Feed, "")
        self.Water = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Water.setObjectName("Water")
        self.graphWidget_2 = MyPlot(self.Water)
        self.graphWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 741, 431))
        self.graphWidget_2.setObjectName("graphWidget_2")
        self.layoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.Water)
        self.layoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 741, 41))
        self.layoutWidget_2.setObjectName("layoutWidget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_7.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_8.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_9.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_10.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_10)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_11)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_12.setFont(font)
        self.label_12.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_12.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_12)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Water, "")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 10, 241, 531))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 221, 501))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.listWidget.setFont(font)
        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item_1 = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        item_1.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item_1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.listViewDClicked)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(-1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def showIntakes(self):
        self.intakes = intakesWindow()
        self.intakes.show()

    def listViewDClicked(self):
        item = self.listWidget.currentItem()
        if item.text() == 'Потребление':
            self.showIntakes()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Feed), _translate("MainWindow", "Feed"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Water), _translate("MainWindow", "Water"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Модули"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Потребление"))
        item_1 = self.listWidget.item(1)
        item_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item1"))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        d = 31
        x = np.arange(d)
        y1 = x
        self.barFeed = MyBarGraphItem()
        self.barFeed.setAttr(brushes=[pg.QtGui.QColor(128, 128, 128) for x in range(d)], x=x, y=y1-0.5*x, height=y1, width= 0.7)

        self.barWater = MyBarGraphItem()
        self.barWater.setAttr(brushes=[pg.QtGui.QColor(0, 139, 139) for x in range(d)],x=x, y=y1-0.5*x, height=y1, width= 0.7)

        self.graphWidget.addBars(self.barFeed)
        self.graphWidget_2.addBars(self.barWater)

class MyBarGraphItem(pg.BarGraphItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def setAttr(self, **opts):
        #print(opts)
        if 'x' in opts:
            self.x = opts['x']
        if 'height' in opts:
            self.height = opts['height']
        if 'width' in opts:
            self.width = opts['width']
        if 'brushes' in opts:
            self.brushes = opts['brushes']
        if 'y' in opts:
            self.y = opts['y']
        super().setOpts(**opts)

## --- > Перенес в модуль    myplot.py   !!!
'''  
class MyPlot(PlotWidget):
    ...
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**intakes.py**

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget

#from untitled2 import MyPlot                              # ---
from myplot import MyPlot                                  # +++

class Ui_intakesWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, intakesWindow):
        intakesWindow.setObjectName("intakesWindow")
        intakesWindow.resize(1417, 910)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(intakesWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        intakesWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        intakesWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1417, 910))
        intakesWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1417, 910))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(intakesWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 621, 761))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_17.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_17.setFont(font)
        self.label_17.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_17)
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget)
        self.spinBox.setEnabled(True)
        self.spinBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.spinBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setWrapping(False)
        self.spinBox.setFrame(False)
        self.spinBox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_18.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_18.setFont(font)
        self.label_18.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_18)
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.widget)
        self.dateEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.dateEdit.setFont(font)
        self.dateEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.dateEdit.setTimeSpec(QtCore.Qt.LocalTime)
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.dateEdit)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.widget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.widget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(639, 10, 771, 891))
        self.widget1.setObjectName("widget1")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget1)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.widget1)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.graphWidget = MyPlot(self.groupBox)
        self.graphWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 751, 351))
        self.graphWidget.setObjectName("graphWidget")
        self.widget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.widget2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 24, 751, 41))
        self.widget2.setObjectName("widget2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget2)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_8.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.widget1)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.graphWidget_2 = MyPlot(self.groupBox_2)
        self.graphWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 751, 351))
        self.graphWidget_2.setObjectName("graphWidget_2")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.groupBox_2)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 24, 751, 41))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_10.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_10)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_11)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_12.setFont(font)
        self.label_12.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_12.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_12)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_13.setFont(font)
        self.label_13.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_13)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_14.setFont(font)
        self.label_14.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_14.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_14)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_15.setFont(font)
        self.label_15.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_15)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_16.setFont(font)
        self.label_16.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.label_16.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_16)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox_2)
        intakesWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(intakesWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(intakesWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, intakesWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        intakesWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("intakesWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "Загон"))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "Дата"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("intakesWindow", "GroupBox"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("intakesWindow", "GroupBox"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("intakesWindow", "TextLabel"))

class intakesWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_intakesWindow):           # +++
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(intakesWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = intakesWindow()                                                # +++
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**myplot.py**

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget

class MyPlot(PlotWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.bars = None
        self.beforeSelected = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        pos = self.getPlotItem().vb.mapSceneToView(ev.pos())
        if self.bars is not None:
            x, y = pos.x(), pos.y()
            #print(f'\nВкладка =  {self.objectName()}')
            if self.objectName() == "graphWidget":
                for i, _ in enumerate(self.bars.x):
                    if self.bars.x[i] - self.bars.width / 2 < x < self.bars.x[i] + self.bars.width / 2 \
                            and 0 < y < self.bars.height[i]:
                        self.selectedBar(i)
                        self.window().label.setText(f'bar = {i}')
                        self.window().label_2.setText(f'x = {x:.5f}')
                        self.window().label_3.setText(f'y = {y:.5f}')
                    ev.accept()
            elif self.objectName() == "graphWidget_2":
                for i, _ in enumerate(self.bars.x):
                    if self.bars.x[i] - self.bars.width / 2 < x < self.bars.x[i] + self.bars.width / 2 \
                            and 0 < y < self.bars.height[i]:
                        self.selectedBar(i)
                        self.window().label_7.setText(f'bar = {i}')
                        self.window().label_8.setText(f'x = {x:.5f}')
                        self.window().label_9.setText(f'y = {y:.5f}')
                    ev.accept()
        super().mousePressEvent(ev)

    def selectedBar(self,i):
        self.selected = i
        if self.beforeSelected is not self.selected:
            b = self.bars.brushes
            b[i] = pg.QtGui.QColor(255, 140, 0)
            self.bars.setAttr(brushes=b)
            if self.beforeSelected is not None:
                if self.objectName() == "graphWidget":
                    b[self.beforeSelected] = pg.QtGui.QColor(128, 128, 128)
                    self.bars.setAttr(brushes=b)
                elif self.objectName() == "graphWidget_2":
                    b[self.beforeSelected] = pg.QtGui.QColor(0, 139, 139)
                    self.bars.setAttr(brushes=b)
        self.beforeSelected = self.selected

    def addBars(self, bars):
        self.bars = bars
        self.addItem(self.bars)
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас рекурсия в импортировании. untitled2.py импортирует intakes.py, а intakes.py иппортирует untitled2.py. MyPlot перенесите в intakes.py

Comment: Ну задумка в том, что бы из intakes.py импортировать окно, а из untitled2.py импортировать класс MyPlot, так как он используется в обоих файлах.